# SSH tunnel through HTTP

Tags: python, tunneling

I got a question: How can I encapsulate a SSH server's output into a HTTP request, only using scripting ?

I want the HTTP request to be valid, with headers and all those things.

Further details: I want to establish a ssh connection between 2 hosts, but i need this connection to be encapsuled into HTTP packets along the way.

Thanks

PS: I do not want to install anything, I want to do this only with scripts.

Edit: As it does not seem clear, I'm not asking for all done scripts by one of you guys.

What I want to know is, what can be done to redirect the output of a SSH server to a text file or anything. I want to take this output and put it into a HTTP request, but I don't know how to "redirect" the output of the SSH server.

This is, amongst other things, what I want to do.

Comment: HTML is not a protocol so you cannot turn something into HTML request. Do you mean HTTP?

Comment: Yes my bad I meant HTTP.

Comment: Well then what did you try/search in order to solve this issue? I can guarantee that people here are not going to build something for you grounds-up if you won't show up some effort on your part.

Comment: My point is, i don't want people to do the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure on the specifics of what you want, but it sounds like it could be accomplished through a CGI script that would start an ssh session, read the data from said session(Which I believe is possible through a child of /dev/, experimentation needed), then sending the data back. Beyond that it's really up to specific implementation.

```
Edit:
Actually a better method might be something like this with a reverse shell.
```